# Getting json content

Tags: javascript, json

I have this URL http://www.spritpreisrechner.at/espritmap-app/GasStationServlet?data=%5B%22Stgilgen%22%2C%22DIE%22%2C13.3597716%2C47.7689327%2C13.3597716%2C47.7689327%5D
As you can see it returns JSON data, I am trying to get those dates with this script

```
$.ajax({ 
type: 'GET', 
url: 'http://www.spritpreisrechner.at/espritmap-app/GasStationServlet?data=%5B%22Stgilgen%22%2C%22DIE%22%2C13.3597716%2C47.7689327%2C13.3597716%2C47.7689327%5D', 
dataType: 'jsonp',
success: function (data) { 
    $( "body" )
        .append( "Kredit: " + data.kredit ) 
        .append( "postalCode: " + data.postalCode ); 
} });
```

But that apparently doesnt work. So if anyone could suggest anything?

Comment: do you own `www.spritpreisrechner.at`? are you running this js from the same domain?

Comment: @lincolnk `dataType: 'jsonp'` would suggest that "no".

Comment: No, but I need those dates for my project

Comment: Well you should study the structure of the JSON response and notice that it's an array.

Comment: `dataType: 'jsonp'` is because otherwise error "access-control-allow-origin" appears.

Comment: And why do you think that is?

Comment: The endpoint spits out JSON, not JSONP. And you can't just force it to do so by setting `dataType: 'jsonp'` in your ajax call. If you are not in control of that endpoint you will have to find a way around, like using a webservice to proxy the data.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"?  Could you be more specific?  Also, sometimes it helps to visualize the JSON response with tools like this:  http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

Answer (score 0):

you should set the "crossDomain" flag to true that way jquery will know you are trying to access other domain, yes should be obvious by the use of jsonp but is not.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

The only option for you would be to work with Spritepreisrechner.at to add your domain to their `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. If you don't have access to that domain (i.e., you don't own it), you're not going to be able to access that.

Another option you have is to leverage the server side of your application to make the request and spit out the response. A sort of proxy page, if you will. If the server side is written in PHP, just as an example, the script could simply contain the following code:

```
<?php echo file_get_contents("http://www.spritpreisrechner.at/espritmap-app/GasStationServlet?data=%5B%22Stgilgen%22%2C%22DIE%22%2C13.3597716%2C47.7689327%2C13.3597716%2C47.7689327%5D");
```

This will not work with `jsonp`, because there is no callback function surrounding the JSON data you're trying to access.

Answer (score 0):

Got the content through

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://jsonp.guffa.com/Proxy.ashx?url=www.spritpreisrechner.at/espritmap-app/GasStationServlet?data=%5B"Stgilgen"%2C"DIE"%2C13.3597716%2C47.7689327%2C13.3597716%2C47.7689327%5D',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

});

Any way thx everyone